# Calculating distance from point to previous point in attribute table

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, distance, fields-attributes

I have a list of points with field data in the attribute table. I want to have the distance between point `id₁` and point `id₁-1` (previous point in table).

Can I write this as a formula in the attribute table to get the result directly there for the same layer?

Answer (score 6):

To calculate the length to the last point in the attribute table, create a new field with field calculator and this expression:

```
length (
    make_line (
        $geometry,
        geometry (
            get_feature_by_id (
                @layer,
                $id-1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From a SQL perspective, using Geopackages, SQLite, PostGIS, etc.:

For something that simple, you can just self-join on `id = id+1`. For something a bit more complex, you can use the [`lag()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/) function. Just bear in mind that not all SQL platforms have the `lag()` function implemented, but since the field, you're joining on is predictable, that's not an issue for your specific question.

```sql
select a.fid,
       st_distance(a.geom,b.geom) as distance, 
       makeline(a.geom,b.geom) as geom
from points a
inner join points b on a.fid = (b.fid + 1)
```

Where fid is your `"id"` field and points your GeoPackage layer name. If you haven't yet discovered the awesome power of GeoPackages and QGIS' DB Manager, just export that layer as a GeoPackage and run the query there, by opening the SQL window after connecting to your GeoPackage:

[image]